# How to display a span tag after page load

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display a span tag only after the page has fully loaded, the span content is generated via a different scrpt and I want to prevent the flicker it show while loading, so I tried the following code to show the tag only once page has fully loaded and content correctly generated by that other script:

```html
<span id="ETOButton" style="display:none;" onload="LoadETOButton()">hello</span>

<script>
function LoadETOButton(){
 document.getElementById("ETOButton").style.display="inline block";
}
</script>
```

what am I doing wrong?

**edit**: the span correctly show after page load, but this created a different issue, now the span is placed outside the div that should contain it, probably wrapper (Wrodpress) is being checked against its content to dedermine the width.

Comment: use document.ready method , write your display='inline block"' code there

Comment: _"the span content is generated via a different script"_ does this script have some sort of callback which you can use to display the span once it has completed?

Comment: @NickParsons I cant edit that part of the script, not under my control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [it](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) is `inline-block` not `inline block`
- You need to call the function `LoadETOButton` in order to do the CSS changes.

```html
<span id="ETOButton" style="display:none;" onload="LoadETOButton()">hello</span>

<script>
function LoadETOButton(){
 document.getElementById("ETOButton").style.display="inline-block";
}

LoadETOButton();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're currently doing is waiting for the span to finish loading before the function is called.

What you need to do instead is add an event listener onto your window, which will be called when the page is done loading.

Also you had a typo with "inline block", it should be "inline-block".

```js
function LoadETOButton() {
  document.getElementById("ETOButton").style.display = "block";
}

window.addEventListener("load", LoadETOButton);
```

```html
<span id="ETOButton" style="display:none;">hello</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code do your work:-

```
function LoadETOButton() {
    document.getElementById("ETOButton").style.display = "block";
                          }

                           window.addEventListener("load", LoadETOButton);
                           <span id="ETOButton" style="display:none;">hello</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use document ready function, if you are using JQuery library

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ETOButton").show(); 
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ETOButton').css('display', 'block');
    });
```

If you want the solution in pure javascript then add load event listener

```
function YourMethodName() {

  document.getElementById("ETOButton").style.display = "block";
}

window.addEventListener("load", YourMethodName)
```

Answer (score 0):

for this you can use native js:

```
<script>
   window.onload = function(){
     document.getElementById("ETOButton").style.display="block";
   }
</script>
```

or jquery:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready( ()=> {
  function LoadETOButton(){
    document.getElementById("ETOButton").style.display="inline block";
  }
  LoadETOButton();
});
</script>
```